# What is the term in Judaism for the "fence laws"? (rabbinical laws to guard against G-d's laws)?

Tags: halacha, words, derabanan

What is the term in Judaism for the "fence laws"? (rabbinical laws to guard against G-d's laws)?

For example the Muktzeh..

Distinguishing it from for example the 7 rabbinical mitzvot / mitzvot r'rabbanan..

Is it that the fence laws are things that are Issur D'Rabbanan, whereas any of the 7 are Mitzvot D'Rabbanan?

Comment: סייג לתורה, גזירות דרבנן, גדר דרבנן

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We normally refer to those as *gezeiros".

Take a look at this old discussion : [What is the difference between a takana and a gezera?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85987/what-is-the-difference-between-a-takana-and-a-gezera)

Comment: Who's "we"? My first thought when I read the question was the word סייג.